# MySQL error #1064 on create table with DOUBLE column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to code this table as it's giving me a #1064 error, and this corresponds to a few potential issues. If someone could point out where I've made a mistake that would be great.

Here is an image of the code I've typed, and the error I've received:

[image: Create table and error 1064]

The code:

```
CREATE TABLE `RENRMyLUoX`.`movie`(
    `mID` INT(20) NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `relYear` YEAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `category` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `runTime` INT(20) NOT NULL,
    `studioName` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `rating` DOUBLE(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`mID`(20))
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin;
```

Comment: What is `int(20)` supposed to be? [See the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DOUBLE` datatype should be specified as either `DOUBLE` or `DOUBLE(m, d)`. I don't understand what `(20)` is supposed to do... you can simply omit it:

```
rating DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense thank you. I'm still fuzzy on how the brackets placed after data types work, so I'll have to learn that a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

TRY BELOW CODE
CREATE TABLE `RENRMyLUoX`.`movie`(
`mID` INT(20) NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`relYear` YEAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`category` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`runTime` INT(20) NOT NULL,
`studioName` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`rating` DOUBLE(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL)ENGINE = InnoDB CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin;

ALTER TABLE `RENRMyLUoX`.`movie`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`mID`)

ALTER TABLE `RENRMyLUoX`.`movie`
MODIFY `mID` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).